# Javascript Forms and Tables script

Tags: javascript, forms, html-table

I need help knowing how to code this. 
in `<script>`
I am trying to learn how to use `<table>` and `<form>.`

**Question:** Write a program using the form that allows you to enter a wholesale price, use a markup of 22% have the retail price be displayed after using the calculate button.

Now, I figured out how to my my from good. I just have absolutely no idea how to go about the coding needed for the calculate button to actually work.

```
<script>

</script>
</body>

    <form name = PriceForm>
    <table border = 1>
    <tr>
       <td>WHOLESALE PRICE:</td>
       <td><input type = “text” name = wsale></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>RETAIL PRICE:</td>
       <td><input type = “text” name = retail></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan = 2><center><input type = button value = "CALCULATE" onClick = "calcfunc()">
        </center></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to give you the answer, but I'll give you a few things to get started.

You'll want a form with two input elements. Then, in the Javascript, you'll want to access these with `document.getElementById("retail").value`, which will give you whatever value is in those elements. Then, you'll want to write some form of math script to mark something up by 22%. To do this, you will have to multiply the original by `.22`.

Comment: okay thank you, sorry if I seemed a little needy for the code, didn't know another way to approach the question

Comment: No problem. We all started somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Looks like homework? I've adjusted your HTML some:

```
<form name="PriceForm">
<table>
<tr>
<td>WHOLESALE PRICE:</td>
<td><input type=“text” name="wsale" id="wsale"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>RETAIL PRICE:</td>
<td><input type=“text” name="retail" id="retail"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick= "calcfunc();">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Next, you'll need to build a function in Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcFunc() {

// get the value of your wholesale price
var retailPrice = document.getElementById("wsale").value;

// now, you need to do your math here 
// manipulate the retailPrice variable here mathematically
// ex: var retailPrice = retailPrice * ...

// finally, alert the value on submit
alert("Retail Price: " + retailPrice);

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add Ids to elements to access
>   Try to mention scripts in head section

Try this

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function calcfunc(){
    var wsale=document.getElementById('wsale').value;
 document.getElementById('retail').value=parseInt(wsale)+parseInt(wsale*.22);
   }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <form name = PriceForm>
       <table border = 1>
       <tr>
   <td>WHOLESALE PRICE:</td>
   <td><input type = “text” id = wsale></td>
       </tr>
<tr>
   <td>RETAIL PRICE:</td>
   <td><input type = “text” id = retail></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan = 2><center><input type = button value = "CALCULATE" onclick = "calcfunc()"></input>
    </center></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

   </body>
```